# Writing GeoPackage with FME - no geometry

Tags: fme-form, geopackage

I have a large amount (400 shapefiles, 11 gigs total) of shapefiles which I would like to store into one file (or DB). I am also using PostGIS, but just out of pure interest I would like try test out how the files would work in a GeoPackage.

I am trying to write the files with FME into a GeoPackage and the features do get transferred and the file gets created, but when I try to open the resulting GeoPackage file on QGIS, it doesn't recognize any geometry in the file.

I was trying to go through the FME help and tried to force the file to create a spatial column, but it still doesn't seem to work as it should. The files contain only polygons and no Z-values. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What if you just do it with one file? I'd suggest making a simple example and posting the shapefile and the Geopackage files here.

Comment: What does ogrinfo find from your geopackage? You can also create GeoPackege with GDAL `ogr2ogr -f gpkg output.gpkg input.shp` For adding more shapefiles into existing gpkg use -append.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! ogrinfo shows that FME doesn't add any geometry in the file like I was guessing. When I do one file with GDAL it works fine and ogrinfo shows polygon geometry. 

But what if I want to add a whole directory of shapes into the geopackage? Just putting *.shp as the input file results in erro message "Couldn't fetch requested layer 'filename.shp'" whereas individual files work just file.

Comment: This still sounds like an FME bug. Have you asked your support contact about this?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the version but I can't reproduce the no geometry problem in FME Desktop 2016.1.0.1. Reading a gpx and writing to a dynamic geopackage writer results in correct geometry tables for Track & Trackpoint and an unknow geometry table for metadata.

Comment: FME writes *GeometryCollection* into a Geopackage and this type of geometry is not supported by QGIS.

If you inspect the Geopackage directly in FME, all geometries should be there.

I have tried to force FME to write *fme-multi* and not *GeometryCollection* when editing a Geopackage file, but I never have found a solution.
Wait and see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281030/export-multipolygons-into-a-geopackage