# Export multipolygons into a GeoPackage

Tags: fme-form, multipart, geopackage, geometrycollection

In FME, I use the Aggregator to merge polygons based on one attribute (*desnat* in my example file).

- When the output is Shapefile, multipolygons are created and all works
  fine.
- When the output is OGC Geopackage or Spatialite, FME creates a
  **GeometryCollection** instead of **multipolygons** (and I can't use
  GeometryCollection with others GIS softwares like QGIS).

I tried to use the GeometryCoercer to force the geometry in *fme_multi*, but nothing is exported.

[image: GeometryCoercer]

I tried to create a new attribute *geopackage_type* with value  *wkb_multi_polygon*. The new attribute is created but the GeometryCoercer can't export anything.

[image: AttributeCreator]

If I remove the GeometryCoercer and I keep the AttributeCreator, the Geopackage is created but with a GeometryCollection and not multipolygons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure which versions you used? I was able to reproduce your problem in FME Desktop 2018.0.0.1 / QGIS Desktop 3.0.2

This behavior is likely to be caused by nested aggregates, created by the Aggregator as the source features already containes aggregates. For example the feature with idobj d3a4eed9-e042-4689-b050-d42c6bf6f248 is an aggregate from 2 areas.

[image: FME Inspector 2018.0.0.1]

Deaggregating them before aggregating solved this:

[image: 2018.0.0.1 FME Desktop Workspace]

[image: AggregatorParameters]

See the result in QGIS.

[image: QGIS Desktop 3.0.2]

Comment: Works well in FME Desktop 2018.0.0.2 and QGIS 2.18.19 + 3.0.2, thanks a lot!

Comment: Deaggregator must be set on "Flatten All Levels"